# Reasons not to use use a wildcard pull?

Tags: clojure, datomic

Are there any reasons not to use a wildcard pull?

```
(defn pull-wild
  "Pulls all attributes of a single entity."
  [db ent-id]
  (d/pull db '[*] ent-id))
```

It's much more convenient than explicitly stating the attributes.

Comment: IMIO (in my ignorant opinion) [by default](http://docs.datomic.com/pull.html), you'll get the [component attributes](http://blog.datomic.com/2013/06/component-entities.html) in full. This could be a lot of work: all those useless order lines for a big order, when all you want is the customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which attributes you need to have in your application and if it's data intensive or whether you want to pull lots of entities.

In case you use the client-library, you might want to minimize the data that needs to be send over the wire.

I guess there are lots of other thoughts about that.

But as long as it's fast enough I would pull the wildcard.

fricke

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in the `entity-map` function [from Tupelo Datomic](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic).  Given an EID (or a Lookup Ref) it will return the full record as a regular Clojure map:

```
(let [
      ; Retrieve James' attr-val pairs as a map. An entity can be referenced either by EID or by a
      ; LookupRef, which is a unique attribute-value pair expressed as a vector.
      james-map   (td/entity-map (live-db) james-eid)                       ; lookup by EID
      james-map2  (td/entity-map (live-db) [:person/name "James Bond"] )    ; lookup by LookupRef
]
  (is (= james-map james-map2
         {:person/name "James Bond" :location "London" :weapon/type #{:weapon/wit :weapon/gun} } ))
```